# Generics in Rust - Iterate and index generic vec (frequency count function)

Tags: generics, rust, casting

I feel this should be easy, but I'm stuck
I can easily do a frequency count of a specific type (like u8), but how can I make it generic to allow counting u32s as well?

```
// Type specific works
fn freqs_u8(data: &[u8], size: usize) -> Vec<u32> {
    data.iter().fold(vec![0_u32; size], |mut freqs, &el| {
        freqs[el as usize] += 1;
        freqs
    })
}

// Not working generic because generic el cannot be typecast to size
fn freqs<T>(data: &[T], size: usize) -> Vec<u32> {
    data.iter().fold(vec![0_u32; size], |mut freqs, &el| {
        freqs[el as usize] += 1;
        freqs
    })
}
```

I've played with where restrictions on T, but to no avail. I've try creating an enum for T that is either a u8 or u32, but I'm not successful there either.

I wonder if I just don't know how to ask the question in the documentation - I've been looking in vain for days.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is no trait to specify for `as`.

There are two possible options:

1. Use [`num-traits`](https://docs.rs/num-traits), that provides the [`AsPrimitive`](https://docs.rs/num-traits/latest/num_traits/cast/trait.AsPrimitive.html) trait:

```rust
fn freqs<T: num_traits::AsPrimitive<usize>>(data: &[T], size: usize) -> Vec<u32> {
    data.iter().fold(vec![0_u32; size], |mut freqs, &el| {
        freqs[el.as_()] += 1;
        freqs
    })
}
```

2. Or better, use [`TryInto`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/trait.TryInto.html), and panic if the value is too big for `usize` (this will be optimized away for types where `usize` is always big enough, e.g. `u32` on 32bit and 64bit platforms):

```rust
fn freqs<T>(data: &[T], size: usize) -> Vec<u32>
where
    T: TryInto<usize> + Copy,
    T::Error: std::fmt::Debug,
{
    data.iter().fold(vec![0_u32; size], |mut freqs, &el| {
        freqs[el.try_into().unwrap()] += 1;
        freqs
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The TryInto looks like a viable option. I'll have to add some safeguards around it to prevent errors. I am hoping to avoid a crate, but will try that avenue as well.